# OleDbException syntax error in insert Statment

Tags: excel, insert, syntax-error, oledbexception

```
static string connStrCheckData = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + Server.MapPath("test.xlsx") + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;";
 
static string      oledbConnCheckData = new OleDbConnection(connStrCheckData);

string adsName ="MagMall.com - subscription savings on 1,000's of magazines";

OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.CommandText = "insert into  [sheet1$] ( [column1]) values ('" + adsName.ToString().Trim() + "')";
cmd.Connection = oledbConnCheckData;

oledbConnCheckData.Open();

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

oledbConnCheckData.Close();
```

> Errro : Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression
> ''MagMall.com - subscription savings on 1,000's of magazines')'.

Above Error occurs when I tried to insert:  "MagMall.com - subscription savings on 1,000's of magazines" word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As juergen said, you hve to escape the single apostrophe buy adding an additional one: 1,000''s (not \'). The double apostrophies is the correct way to pass the statement.

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape the `'` in `1,000's` like this `1,000\'s`

Comment: Can hyphen "-"    generates any  problem .  And value of adsName  changes every time in loop then how can i applied escape  in variable .

Comment: I did like adsName.ToString().Trim().Replace("'", "\'") but still giving error .

Comment: @Shailesh: Try `adsName.ToString().Trim().Replace("'", "\\'")`